# How to call functions from a file in Python?

Tags: python, windows, module, python-idle

I am very new to Python. I've learned recently that we could store all our defined functions in one file and call them up when we need it. I'm using Idle on Windows.

Where should I store the .py file that will contain all the functions so they can be accessed from Idle, and how should I call it?

Answer (score 2):

```
Some Folder
|
  - my_funcs.py
|
  - other.py
```

other.py

```
from my_funcs import somefunc
somefunc("An Argument")
```

my_funcs.py

```
def somefunc(s):
    print "SomeFunction:%s"%s
```

then run other.py

Answer (score 1):

The file must be on your PYTHONPATH.  You need to set that in your environment.  e.g. if your file is:

```
C:/path/to/myfile.py
```

Then you need to make sure that `C:/path/to` is on PYTHONPATH.  Then, in another script, you can import `myfile` via:

```
import myfile
```

Now you can use a function (`func`) defined in `myfile` as:

```
myfile.func()
```

Answer (score 1):

Say you are testing a function and you would like to see it working on the fly:
this is the usual sequence

- you have "IDLE" open as main shell
- from Idle you open a new file where you write your commands or a function
- you make this module run from RUN -> MODULE or press F5
- this starts your module on Idle or generates an error warning (such as a wrong indentation)

Now it is 2 cases:

- either your module is bare commands: then they will be executed immediately on Idle shell
- or your module is a function, then you need to call it as it is meant to, with or without arguments; eg: *myFunction()* or *secondsInYears(5)*

That is what it all should be.

**Comment**. Differently from compiling and testing in C, where you only need a text-editor to compile through Command line and a compiler (to avoid opening clunky dev-env's); in Python paradoxically such a workflow turns even too demanding to be an alternative to the native IDLE as you need to be specific each time. I hope it helps